# How to custom the camera style in phonegap for Android application

Tags: android, html, cordova, camera

I am creating a Android application using camera. Now, I want to customize the camera to look like the following image:[image: sample]

How to customize this type of camera in phonegap for the Android application?

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be creating a plugin to do this. As @Shoaib Chikate pointed out, PhoneGap uses the Native camera of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap uses the native camera of the particular platform.
 So for Android it would be different, and for iOS it would be different
.

So in order to make custom camera, you should follow the approach of the particular platform.

[Controlling camera using android approach](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)